# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to connect from Linux Centos7 with Cpanel on, to a remote SQL Server.

I have installed pdo_sqlsrv, its there in Php Info.

I have installed ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, as per this output:

```
[root@myserver ~]# odbcinst -q -d -n "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server"
[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1
```

But my PHP script shows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 in /home/mysite/public_html/dev/stock-import.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/mysite/public_html/dev/stock-import.php(17): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=1...', 'myusername', 'mypassword') #1 {main} thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/dev/stock-import.php on line 17

So its installed.

Any ideas?

PHP code is:

```
$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=$server:$port", $user, $pass );
```

Update: Actually, the error I used to get before installing ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server said to install ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, so specifically version 11, but after installing version 11, the error does not show the version.

Update: If I use odbc_connect I get:

> odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired, SQL state S1T00 in SQLConnect

Update: It’s working now. I’ve uninstalled the ODBC Manager 2.3.0 and Driver 11 and installed ODBC Manager 2.3.7 and Driver 17 and it’s working now.

Comment: Its not that though, I dont even get that far I cant connect. Have removed that line to avoid confusion, same error. Also changed code it to just the following without running any database queries and get same error. $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

Comment: What is bit architecture of your Linux system: 32 or 64? You need to download the ODBC driver consistent to PHP client's (not server's) OS and bit type. First error suggests an incompatible driver. ODBC Driver 11 is an older version mainly for Windows for MSSQL <= 2014. What version is remote database? Also, advise if remote database is running in Windows or Linux.

Comment: It’s not very clear online what versions to use. The MS install instructions don’t mention it I don’t think. I followed some instructions and the error was to install version 11. I’ve uninstalled the ODBC Manager 2.3.0 and Driver 11 and installed ODBC Manager 2.3.7 and Driver 17 and it’s working now, to connect to an Azure database.

Comment: Yes, always look to latest ODBC versions which usually are backwards compatible.